# Cannot read state from Redux store. What did I miss?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my `index.js` where I initially dispatch an action to read my list of locations:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from  'react-dom';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import {loadLocationList} from './actions/locationActions';
import './css/styles.css';

const store = configureStore();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then here is my action where I get the data & then create an action out of it:

```
export function loadLocationListSuccess(alistingData) {
    return { type: types.LOAD_LOCATION_LIST_SUCCESS, listingData: alistingData};
}

export function loadLocationList() {
        return function(dispatch){ //we return a function that accepts a parameter, we just called it dispatch
            //dispatch(fetchCallActions.fetchCallStart("")); // we dispatch a function fetchCallStart to indicate the start of our call, this is to keep in check with our asynchronous function calls
            let link = 'http://example.com:8399/location';//our fetch url
            console.log(link); //we log our link, just for debug purposes

            return fetch(link) //start fetch
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(json) {
                dispatch(loadLocationListSuccess(json));
            }).catch(function(ex) {
                console.log('parsing failed', ex);

            });
        };
    }
```

Then here is my reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function locationReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_LOCATION_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {listingData: action.listingData};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then here is my `mapStateToProps` & `connect` function:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
      return {
        // we'll call this in our component -> this.props.listingData
        listingData: state.listingData
      };
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(homePage);
```

For some reason, it cannot read `state.listingData` or am I actually doing it wrongly? Anyone can help me with this problem?

I tried logging `state.listingData` and it showed `undefined`

Here is my `configureStore`:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant())
    );
}
```

Here is my combined Reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import courses from './courseReducer';
import locations from './locationReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    courses,
    locations
});


export default rootReducer;
```

Did I not connect it to the store properly?

**Recent update**:
Logging `JSON.stringify(state)` in `mapStateToProps` would actually shows the result. Thanks guys.

The correct path turned out to be `state.locations.listingData` because I think in my combined Reducer I included the reducer as `locations` so maybe thats why the state for it is `state.locations`. Hope this helps anyone with the problem.

Comment: We can't know if you connected it to the store properly since the code that's trying to connect it to the store is missing :) Have you looked at the [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples) for react-redux and how they use the `connect` function?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enough detail here. (More of an aside, but default state should be an object and not an array)

Comment: @ivarni I've edited my post, you can see how I used the `connect` function.  @Gosha Arinich well I'm merely refering to a working project and they used objects for it. Anything you might think I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Can you show the code of configureStore file? The problem might be there, may be you forgot to add reducer to list of reducers.
- Does the action works right? Did you log data before `dispatch(loadLocationListSuccess(json));`?

UPD:

Because of rootReducer. Each reducer creates their own key in store. When you combine your reducers in rootReducer, like:

```
import locations from './locationReducer';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    courses,
    locations
});
```

It creates store with this kind of structure:

```
const store = {
    courses: {},
    locations: {}
}
```

So, after that you dispatched action and reducer changed the data to this:

```
const store = {
    courses: {},
    locations: {
       listingData: someData
    }
}
```

If you want to access to listingData like: state.listingData, you need to change a little your reducer and combineReducer to:

```
export default function listingData(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_LOCATION_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return action.listingData;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

...

import listingData from './locationReducer';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    courses,
    listingData
});
```

Comment: I've edited my post for the `configureStore`. I've already added my reducer to my combined `rootReducer`. Also, I managed to log the data before `dispatch(loadLocationListSuccess(json));`. So it should be working. I can show you my `rootReducer` if you need to see it.

Comment: Yeah, please show me the rootReducer. Because i think, to access to listingData, you need to write something like `state.locationReducer.listingData`, but it depends on rootReducer. Also, console.log whole state in mapStateToProps in JSON format to see the structure, may be you will see the correct path to listingData

Comment: I've updated my post. I've found the correct path of it which is `state.locations.listingData`. Just a question, why is it not `state.listingData` instead? The codes I provided in my post are the same.

Comment: For future reference, ask for clarifications in comments, post answer once you have a full answer.